How to drop rows with empty values in Huggingface dataset?
After I have loaded a huggingface dataset
download_config = DownloadConfig()
dataset = load_dataset (hf_dataset_name, download_config=download_config)
dataset_split = dataset ['train']

Let say if there is None or "" found in the row of column "answer", how do I drop the row?

HuggingFace datasets wrap around PyArrow Datasets which can be filtered:
import pyarray.dataset as ds

mask = ds.field('answer') is None | ds.field('answer') == ''
filtered = dataset_split.data.filter(~mask).to_table()

